# How can I set the ValidateAntiForgeryToken globally

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, action-filter

Security at first.

MVC best practices reccomend to add the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute to each `[HttpPost]` action.

How can I enforce this rule in one unique point of the application?

Answer (score 18):

The follwing class allow to do this with a FilterProvider

```
public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
{
    List<Filter> result = new List<Filter>();

    string incomingVerb = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod;

    if (String.Equals(incomingVerb, "POST", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        result.Add(new Filter(new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute(), FilterScope.Global, null));
    }

    return result;
}
```

To use the above class add this to the `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in `global.asx` file:

```
...    
FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new AntiForgeryTokenFilterProvider ());
..
```

Doing this, each `[HttpPost]` will check if the `Html.AntiForgeryToken()` is in the view.

Comment: Does your filter provider inherit from any base class?

Comment: The code will cause a list to be created for every request to the application. It can be improved by using yield: yield return new Filter(new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute(), FilterScope.Global, null);

Comment: link to the full class for clarities sake: https://code.google.com/p/vnecoo/source/browse/trunk/Code/Oas2011/OAS/Helpers/AntiForgeryTokenFilterProvider.cs?r=148