# How to override `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` at method level?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, antiforgerytoken

I have `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` attribute applied at class level. As shown in the below code.

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken, Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser")]
public class ManageController : BaseController
{
...
}
```

This class has several methods which accepts `POST` data and couple of methods which are exposed for `GET` operation. I would like to disable `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` for `GET` method **without changing class level attribute**. I know that I can do this by changing all the `POST` methods and applying `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` just to them. But I am hoping their is an easy way.

Just like the way `Authorize` attribute works along with `AllowAnonymous` where you can apply `Authorize` attribute at class level but then can change it method level by applying `AllowAnonymous`.

```
[Authorize]
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {            
            return View();
        }
}
```

Comment: look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213345/how-can-i-set-the-validateantiforgerytoken-globally, basically you can create a filter, add the filter to the class and then the filter will add the ValidateAntiForgeryToken just to the post methods

Answer (score 0):

I think this post will help you.
http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2012/7/securing_all_forms_using_antiforgerytoken

By adding a custom IAuthorizationFilter you can skip checking GET

```
public class AntiForgeryAttribute: IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext authorizationContext)
    {
        if (authorizationContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod != "POST")
            return;

        new ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute().OnAuthorization(authorizationContext);
    }
}
```

Or later on in the article it explains how to create a custom attribute to skip validating some actions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please describe the answers more. when you have a link in your answer, it is probable that the page get removed and your answer get useless for other people in the future

Comment: May be I am not following the article correctly and making mistake. I have uploaded code at https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5sbaoysbb0ayt7/AntifForgerySkip.zip?dl=0 could you please have a look? I also tried using a base class.